# Execution failed for task ':bootRun'. SpringBoot Gradle

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, bootrun

I thank you in advance for your help

I am currently starting a Spring Boot project (Gradle) and when I run the `./gradlew bootRun` command on my VScode terminal, I get the following message:

---

APPLICATION FAILED TO START

---

Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.

> Task :bootRun FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.

> Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-17.0.5.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

The problem is that I wasn't using my port 8080 at all (unless I'm mistaken, and if I am I don't know how to check it).

I feel more like I have a problem with my JAVA.

I will be very grateful to you for helping me find a solution to this problem. Thanking you in advance :)

Comment: On Linux, you can check with `lsof`: `lsof -i | grep :8080`, on MacOS use `lsof -i -P | grep :8080`. No idea how to do this on Windows. Maybe your previous run didn't terminate. Check if something is still running. Maybe restarting VS Code helps.

Answer (score 1):

#### Windows

`netstat -aon | findstr 8080`

#### Unix/Linux/Mac

`lsof -i :8080`

Then you can proceed/kill with (process explorer/)`tasklist/ps`... Thx to:

- https://dzone.com/articles/how-to-check-which-process-is-using-port-8080-or-a
- https://mkyong.com/linux/linux-which-application-is-using-port-8080/
- https://mkyong.com/mac/mac-osx-what-program-is-using-port-8080/

Answer (score 0):

It has never happened to me before, But some other application can be using port `8080`

You can check with CMD as Administrator by using `netstat` command like this

```
netstat -a -b | findstr "8080"
```

This will show who is using this port.

To overcome this issue, You can easily go to `application.properties` and add

```
server.port = 8081
```

This will make the application to be run over port `8081` all the time.

And you can do it with one time setup by adding args to `gradle bootrun` like this

```
gradle bootrun --args='--server.port=8081'
```

This will result of running the server over port `8081` for one time only.